# SEO and case sensitive url issue

Tags: seo, url-rewrite-module

We have a web site with following url:

```
http://www.sitename.ru/Order.aspx?ActionID=39028
```

But, the url could be written in this way as well (case sensitive):

```
http://www.sitename.ru/ORDer.aspX?ActionID=39028
http://www.sitename.ru/ORDER.ASPX?ActionID=39028
```

and so on.

From the SEO (Google) point of view, it's not good because there could be a lot of double urls.

Is there any way to fix this and not to loose all already indexed pages with this form of url:

```
http://www.sitename.ru/Order.aspx?ActionID=39028
```

Of course, there are a lot of different other pages whose urls also can be written in case sensitive way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either configuring your application server, or your web server to send a [301 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirecting users who are using the wrong capitalisation.

This is the approach that [Google recommends](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).